# KQL Azure Alert only fire if other event has not been logged

Tags: azure, kql, azure-log-analytics, azure-sentinel

I have a basic azure alert where it looks at the windows logs of a VM, and determines whether it should fire an alert upon detecting a specific event ID

`Event | where EventID == "500" | summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by ParameterXml | project TimeGenerated, Computer, EventID, RenderedDescription | order by TimeGenerated`

The conditions are whether the event is detected once or more in the space of 5 minutes. I'm looking to have some alert logic in there where it only fires, if additional alert event "650" has **not** fired.

I have tried using joins to attach the additional event ID onto the query, but unsure how to parse the logic to say **not** fired

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-log-query (Example 4)

**Summary**

Fire alert if event id 500 detected **and** event id 650 not detected

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
Event
| where EventID in (500, 650)
| summarize
    arg_max(iff(EventID == 500, TimeGenerated, datetime(null)), *),
    Cond= countif(EventID == 650) == 0
    by Computer
| where Cond
| project TimeGenerated, Computer, EventID, RenderedDescription
| order by TimeGenerated
```

The summarize line filters the newest event with ID 500 and counts the events with ID 650.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution with join leftanti:

```
Event
| where EventID in (500, 650)
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by EventID, Computer
| as T
| where EventID == 500
| join kind=leftanti (T | where EventID == 650) on Computer
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I will be trying this shortly. I didn't mention it in my post but would this easily cover say, - if event 650 is not found in 5 minutes?

Comment: You can use the join with kind=leftouter. The leftouter join result has TimeGenerated and TimeGenerated1. The TimeGenerated1 is null in the case of missing event 650. Both times can be used to filter the final result.

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a try. Trying the original solution first, running the query unfortunately returns zero results. Removing the line 'join kind=leftanti' line however does (just displays all the times it has logged event 500). For this test, I am manually writing log 500 to the VM, purposely missing out event 650